# Make form fields required

Tags: php, forms, field

I've tried to work with `isset()` to add required fields to my form as you can see below, but is this sufficient?
It only works for one field: `ik_wens`, because it's a checkbox. The form ignores the uncompleted textfields and just sends the e-mail.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    if (    !isset($_POST['naam']) ||
            !isset($_POST['adres']) ||
            !isset($_POST['tel']) ||
            !isset($_POST['datum_gourmet_fondue']) || 
            !isset($_POST['aantal_personen'])|| 
            !isset($_POST['ik_wens'])|| 
            !isset($_POST['graag'])
        ) {  
         echo 'U heeft niet alle velden ingevuld!';  
         exit;      
     } 

     $to = 'info@yourmail.nl'; 
     $onderwerp = " Gourmet/ fonduelijst "; ;

     $naam = htmlspecialchars($_POST['naam']); 
     $adres = htmlspecialchars($_POST['adres']);
     $tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel']);  
     $datum_gourmet_fondue = htmlspecialchars($_POST['datum_gourmet_fondue']);  
     $aantal_personen = htmlspecialchars($_POST['aantal_personen']);  
     $wish = $_POST["ik_wens"];
     $graag = htmlspecialchars($_POST['graag']); 

     $details = "
       Onderwerp: $onderwerp\n\n\n
       Naam: $naam\n\n
       Adres: $adres\n\n
       Tel.: $tel \n\n
       Datum gourmet/ fondue: $datum_gourmet_fondue \n\n
       Aantal personen: $aantal_personen \n\n
       Ik wens:  $wish \n\n
       Graag: $graag 
      ";

     // Send the message
     $ok = mail($to, $onderwerp, $details);
     if ($ok) {
         echo "<p>E-mail is verzonden</p>";
     } else {
         echo "<p>E-Mail is niet verzonden, probeer opnieuw!</p>";
     }
?>
```

Comment: Be aware that not all browsers allow multi-line string constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `isset`, which returns `true` for all elements that were present in the form. You want `empty` instead.

http://php.net/empty